# Extract substrings with certain length randomly from a file with Bash

Tags: bash, random, substring

I have multiple text files, and from each file I need to extract random contiguous substrings with a certain length.

For example, I need to extract Five random substrings that consist of 3 contiguous characters each, or 4 random substrings that consist of 20 characters each.

In practice, let's assume this is the content of one of the files

```
Welcome to stackoverflow the best technical resource ever
```

so if I want Five random substrings that consist of 3 characters each, I expect an output that looks like this for example:

```
elc
sta
tec
res
rce
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: how do you plan to get 20 contiguous chars if the longest word is shorter than that?  Are you concatenating the words to eliminates spaces?

Comment: I don't care about certain words, space is an acceptable character for me.

Comment: For example if I want 10 random characters, then these would be acceptable:
"Welcome to"
 "stackoverf" 
" best tech"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -v n=5 -v s=3  'BEGIN {srand()}
                          {len=length($0); 
                           for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                              {k=rand()*(len-s)+1; printf "%s\t", substr($0,k,s)}
                               print ""}' file
```

there may be spaces in the extracted substrings

Comment: I receive this error:

./script.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./script.sh: line 3: `awk -v n=5 -v s=3 ''BEGIN {srand()}'

Comment: there were two single quotes before `BEGIN`, there should be only one.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to pick a random substring:

```
random_string() {
  line=$1
  length=$2
  # make sure we start at a random position that guarantees a substring of given length
  start=$((RANDOM % ((${#line} - $length))))
  # use Bash brace expansion to extract substring
  printf '%s' "${line:$start:$length}"
}
```

Use the function in a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  random1=$(random_string "$line" 3)
  random2=$(random_string "$line" 20)
  printf 'random1=[%s], random2=[%s]\n' "$random1" "$random2"
done < file
```

Sample output with the content `Welcome to stackoverflow the best technical resource ever` in `file`:

```
random1=[hni], random2=[low the best technic]
random1=[sta], random2=[e best technical res]
random1=[ove], random2=[ackoverflow the best]
random1=[rfl], random2=[echnical resource ev]
random1=[ech], random2=[est technical resour]
random1=[cal], random2=[ome to stackoverflow]
random1=[tec], random2=[o stackoverflow the ]
random1=[l r], random2=[come to stackoverflo]
random1=[erf], random2=[ stackoverflow the b]
random1=[me ], random2=[ the best technical ]
random1=[est], random2=[ckoverflow the best ]
random1=[tac], random2=[tackoverflow the bes]
random1=[e t], random2=[o stackoverflow the ]
random1=[al ], random2=[come to stackoverflo]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great, but there is one problem, many of the strings that had a space at their end got removed!

Comment: `IFS=` was missing in `read -r`.  Added that and that would take care of the trailing space issue.